# Unusual Livewire Behaviour: object become empty array

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a component where I display the list of transactions and show details of each transaction using a modal.

```
class TableTranscation extends Component
{
    use WithPagination, Alert, AuthorizesRequests;

    ...
    public $transaction;
    public $detailModal = false;

    public function showDetail($id)
    {
        $this->transaction = Transaction::find($id);
        $this->detailModal = true;

        //dd transaction variable here return correct result
        //dd($this->transaction);
    }    

    public function render()
    {
        return view("livewire.user.transaction.transaction-table", [
            "transactions" => current_user()->transactions()->paginate($this->perPage)
        ]);
    }
}
```

Whenever I call to showDetail method from the component, the transaction remains Array[0] in Livewire devtool.

[image: Livewire debug tool]

I tried adding the mount method but the Livewire devtool also showed Array[0].

```
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->transaction = Transaction::find(1);
    }
```

When I {{ dd($transaction) }} from the view it return correct transaction.

Any solution to this problem or bug from the tool?

Comment: I've never used that tool in particular, but if the code works, and the only issue is how it looks in the devtool, then it's likely the devtool. Try another tool, like Laravel Debugbar by Barry

Comment: Everything looks find with Laravel Debugbar @Qirel